# Combine API results from multiple arrays into a single array in a React.js component

Tags: reactjs

I have the following React.js component where I get 10 multiple-choice trivia questions via an API call using fetch and recursively list them on the page via nested components.

The API provides 'correct_answer' as string, and 'incorrect_answers' separately as an array of strings. In my current code, I am only able to list the 'correct' and 'incorrect' answers in their own components.

What I would like to do is combine the 'correct' and 'incorrect' answers into a single array and then randomise the output of them, so that the correct answer is not always in the same place in the list. How would I alter my current code to that? I am an absolute beginner at React.js so any pointers are welcome, thanks.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

    class QuestionContainer extends Component {

        constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = {
                questions: []
            };
        }

        componentWillMount() {
            const RenderHTMLQuestion = (props) => (<p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:props.HTML}}></p>)
            const RenderHTMLAnswer = (props) => (<li dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:props.HTML}}></li>)
            fetch('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&category=9&type=multiple')
                .then(results => {
                    return results.json();
                }).then(data => {
                    let questions = data.results.map((question, index) => {
                        return(
                            <div key={index} className="questionWrapper">
                                <div className="question" key={question.question}>
                                     <RenderHTMLQuestion HTML={question.question} />
                                </div>
                                <ul className="answers">
                                    <RenderHTMLAnswer key={question.correct_answer} HTML={question.correct_answer} />

                                   {question.incorrect_answers.map((answer, index) => (
                                        <RenderHTMLAnswer key={index} HTML={answer} />
                                    ))}
                               </ul>
                            </div>
                        )
                    })

                    this.setState({questions: questions});
                })

            }


        render() {
            return (
                <div className="container2">
                    {this.state.questions}
                </div>
            )
        }
    }


    export default QuestionContainer;
```

Comment: Hi, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,

```
let questions = data.results.map((question, index) => {
  let correctAnswer = false
  return (
    <div key={index} className="questionWrapper">
      <div className="question" key={question.question}>
           <RenderHTMLQuestion HTML={question.question} />
      </div>
      <ul className="answers">
        {question.incorrect_answers.map((answer, index) => {    
            if(Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(question.incorrect_answers.length-1)) === index && !correctAnswer) {
                  correctAnswer = true
                  return <> <RenderHTMLAnswer key={question.correct_answer} HTML={question.correct_answer} /> <RenderHTMLAnswer key={index} HTML={answer} /> </>
             }
            return <RenderHTMLAnswer key={index} HTML={answer} />
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
})
```

[Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

**Note:** Don't use `componentWillMount` **(UNSAFE)**, instead you can go for `componentDidMount` for your API call.

---

**Update**

You can also try this,

```
let questions = data.results.map((question, index) => {
  question.incorrect_answers.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(question.incorrect_answers.length + 1)), 0, question.correct_answer)
  return (
    <div key={index} className="questionWrapper">
      <div className="question" key={question.question}>
          <RenderHTMLQuestion HTML={question.question} />
      </div>
      <ul className="answers">
        {question.incorrect_answers.map((answer, index) => { 
            return <RenderHTMLAnswer key={index} HTML={answer} />
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
})
```

[Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-h5vfbf)

Comment: Thanks, this is moving in the right direction, it does randomise the output, but it is not outputting all of the incorrect answers (there are 3 incorrect and 1 correct answers provided from the API) and it is sometimes adding the correct answer more than once. e.g. The first three items list out as:

Question
correct answer
correct answer
incorrect answer

Question
incorrect answer
correct answer
incorrect answer

Question
correct answer
correct answer
incorrect answer

So the logic needs to be adjusted somewhere I think?

Comment: I think part of the problem is that '{question.incorrect_answers.map((answer, index)...' only iterates 3 times as there are 3 incorrect answers. I need to be able to add the 4th correct answer in there at a random point.

Comment: Thanks, that is now adding the additional answer but is adding the correct answer twice in some instances. e.g. Question1: incorrect, correct, incorrect, incorrect (this is how it should be). Question 2: correct, incorrect, correct, incorrect, incorrect (this has the correct answer duplicated).

Comment: @SilentDesigns, try adding a flag as updated in answer.

Comment: This is still adding duplicate correct answers and sometimes omitting the correct answer. Thanks for your help, I'll look at this again after some sleep!

Comment: @SilentDesigns, Have you added `&& !correctAnswer` in if condition?

Comment: @ravibaul91 Thanks, splicing the correct answer into the incorrect_answer array was the solution. Thanks for your efforts looking at this. I will mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using lodash
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#shuffle

```
const answers = _.shuffle(_.concat(correct_answers, incorrect_answers));
return (
 <ul className="answers">
  {answers.map((answer, index) => (<RenderHTMLAnswer key={index} HTML={answer} />))}
 </ul>
)
```

Comment: I don't think this will work, because as stated in my question 'correct_answer' is a string, not an array.

Comment: @SilentDesigns that can be easily fixed by changing the code above to something like: `const answers = _.shuffle([correct_answer, ...incorrect_answers]);`. I'd also recommend keeping the key the answer itself instead of using the index